# ActionBar dont show divider between items with icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, divider

Default behavior is that divider is show only between text items in ActionBar, but I need insert divider between all items in ActionBar. How can I do it? I am using Support library for support 2.1+ android devices.

Using custom XML style dont help, its change only showed dividers

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarDivider">@drawable/divider</item>
    <item name="divider">@drawable/divider</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar style -->
<style name="ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
```